# Closure of a set depends on the norm.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let C$[0,1]$ be the space of continuous real valued functions on the interval $[0,1]$, let $W$ be the set consisting of functions of the form
$$
f_n(x)=\begin{cases} nx \mbox{ on } [0,1/n]\\ 1 \mbox{ on } [1/n,1] \end{cases}
$$
for $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$. What is the limit of $(f_n)$ with respect to the $\infty$-norm?

Comment: Does it even have a limit with respect to the $\infty$-norm? Is the pointwise limit continuous on $[0,1]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try drawing a picture. This will help show that the sequence has no limit.

Note that $f_n(\frac{1}{2n}) = \frac{1}{2}$, $f_{2n}(\frac{1}{2n}) = 1$ for all $n$. Hence $\|f_n - f_{2n}\|_\infty \geq \frac{1}{2}$ for all $n$, and so $f_n$ is not Cauchy, hence it does not converge.

In fact, a similar analysis shows that if $m<n$, then $\|f_n-f_m\|_\infty \geq 1-\frac{m}{n}$. Hence if $f_{n_k}$ is a subsequence, then it is straightforward to show using this observation that $f_{n_k}$ cannot be Cauchy.

If you let $\Phi= \{ f_n \}$, then the above observation shows that $\Phi$ has no accumulation points. It follows from this that $\Phi$ is closed.

To see this, suppose $g \notin \Phi$. Then there exists some $\delta>0$ such that $\|g-f_n\|_\infty \geq \delta$ for all $n$, because if not, then there would be some subsequence $f_{n_k} \to g$, which would imply that $f_{n_k}$ is Cauchy, a contradiction. Hence $B(g,\delta) \cap \Phi = \emptyset$, from which it follows that $\Phi^C$ is open.